# HDInsight and Reading Blob Files Cluster Size

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I'm an HDInsight/Hadoop newbie, but I'm trying to use HDInsight to pull in all of our raw IIS log files from our Azure App Service plans that are stored in an Azure Blob container so that I can do some analysis and query some statistics.  We have about 240,000 log files totally around 36GB within one Blob container.  I tried spinning up a 4 worker node cluster with D3_V2 VM size and doing:

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IISLogs (
    s_date date, 
    s_time string, 
    s_sitename string, 
    ....
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://xxxx@xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/' 
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="2");
```

However after about 11-12 hours of this experiment, it timed out.

Does anyone have any experience loading in similar amount of files from Azure Blob storage?  What did you use for cluster size (worker count and VM size) and what was the timing to create the table?  Is there a better way to do what I"m trying to do?

Comment: So every file is ~300KB big? That won't work with Hadoop at all. Go and write a combiner that batches them up to 512mb or more.

Comment: For my knowledge why?  Hadoop doesn't do well with huge number of small files?  Why 512mb?

Comment: read up on http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/ as for the 512mb, we did benchmarks and found this to be the optimal number on blobs <-> hdinsight

Comment: Appreciate the info and link, thanks.